# How to install Lattice's iCEcube2 on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation

Currently I am running [Lattice's iCEcube2](https://www.latticesemi.com/iCEcube2) on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, no problems. Now I want to install it on a Raspberry Pi. When I run the installer I get

```
-bash: ./iCEcube2setup_Dec_10_2020_2012: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pi has an ARM processor.  This is not compatible with the Intel or AMD processors probably running in your desktop and laptop computers.

You need to find a version compiled to run on ARM (of course there my be no such version).